# AR Parrot navigation board pinout

Tags: pinout, drone

[image: ultrasonic ping sensor]

Does anyone know which pins do what on the AR Parrots navigation board?

Comment: Isn't that header simply the connection between the nav board and the motherboard? It's likely some serial protocol plus power and other stuff. Easiest way to figure out what flavour of protocol it is would be to throw a scope on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what the probable pinout is from [here](http://embedded-software.blogspot.com/2011/01/reading-navigation-data-directly-from.html). In the comments of the link Anonymous says the pinouts are probably:

1. : +Vcc (5v)
2. : PGED2/RP10(1)/CN16/PMD2/RB10 (8) (ICSP)
3. : Txd (to Navboard)
4. : PGEC2/RP11(1)/CN15/PMD1/RB11 (9) (ICSP)
5. : Rxd (from Navboard)
6. :/MCLEAR (18)
7. : GND
8. : GND